# webpack style-loader HMR sourcemaps aren't updating

Tags: css, webpack, webpack-hmr

I've got HMR working, and changes to my styles do update on the page automatically. However, HMR is not updating the source map for my styles, so when I click on a style while inspecting an element, I can only see the version of the file as it appeared when the page first loaded.

My loader is:

```
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  include: SRC,
  loaders: ["style", "css?module&sourceMap&importLoaders=1", "postcss"]
}
```

And I've configured `devtool` to be `cheap-module-eval-source-map`.

How can I get the sourcemap to update with the changes?

Comment: Have you figured this out?

Comment: Sadly, no... are you having the same issue?